# FindNextFile Faild with Space Character

Tags: c++, winapi

I wrote a simple code to do some operation on every file in every folder (subfolders).
It's perfectly works until the path comes with 'SPACE
' character program crashs and `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` has been called. This is function:

```
int dirListFiles(char* startDir)
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA  wfd;
    char path[MAX_PATH];

    sprintf(path, "%s\\*", startDir);

    std::string fileName;
    std::string s_path = startDir;
    std::string fullPath;

    fprintf(stdout, "In Directory \"%s\"\n\n", startDir);

    if ((hFind = FindFirstFileA(path, &wfd)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("FindFirstFIle failed on path = \"%s\"\n", path);
        abort();
    }

    BOOL cont = TRUE;
    while (cont == TRUE)
    {
        if ((strncmp(".", wfd.cFileName, 1) != 0) && (strncmp("..", wfd.cFileName, 2) != 0))
        {
            if (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                sprintf(path, "%s\\%s", startDir, wfd.cFileName);
                dirListFiles(path);
            }
        else
        {
            fileName = wfd.cFileName;
            fullPath = s_path + "\\" + fileName;    

            std::string fileExt = PathFindExtension(fullPath.c_str());
            if (fileExt == ".cpp")
            {
                ... Some operation on file
            }
        }
    }
    cont = FindNextFile(hFind, &wfd);
}

FindClose(hFind);
```

For example, If `FindNextFile` wants to Open `Program Files (x86)` which has space between file name cause error and program exit. What Can I do for supporting spaces? What Is Problem?

Comment: You should call `GetLastError` and inspect the value returned.

Comment: nothing need do. space is usual character. and why somebody still use `FindFirstFileA` instead `FindFirstFileEx` how minimum ?

Comment: @RbMm Does it make a difference in this situation?

Comment: in performance difference huge.

Comment: code in all case have many mistakes. for example you fail with long paths (> MAX_PATH), etc.

Comment: I think it may be wrong before hand, and perhaps command line arguments have split on space.

Comment: first of all very common mistake - how file paths is processed. you need at begin once allocate `0x8000` *wchar* length buffer and pass it to function with current position in buffer to where need append \ and mask. and of course never use *A* api, only *W*,

Comment: @RbMm Yes I figured out the main problem is `string` and `char*` it should be allocated and `wstring`  or(`LPCWSTR`) ,  `wchar_t` instead of those.

Comment: @mksteve No I initial value in the source.

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin - you need only once allocate maximum path length buffer which is `0x8000` *wchar* (64kb). after this you never need allocate any names. you simply need append file names to current position in buffer

Comment: Maybe the path doesn't contain a space character, but rather a Unicode code point, that cannot be represented in the ANSI codepage you decided to use. Incidentally, why aren't you using Unicode? Or a [recursive_directory_iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/recursive-directory-iterator-class) for that matter?

Comment: Should I Use `HealAlloc` or `malloc`? How?

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin - how you think - what different ?  you can simply allocate it in stack as local var before first function call `WCHAR buf[0x8000];`

Comment: `WIN32_FIND_DATA` also much better once declare before recursive function call and pass it as pointer, instead declare it inside function (too large structure for recursive call)

Comment: If you need to support paths longer than `MAX_PATH` or unusual names, then begin by normalizing the input path to an extended path. Ensure the input path ends with a backslash and call `GetFullPathName`. Then handle the various input cases -- paths that are already extended with `L"\\\\?\\"`; local-device paths that start with `L"\\\\.\\"` for which you replace "." with "?"; logical-drive-letter paths that need to be prefixed by `L"\\\\?\\"`; and UNC paths that need to be written as `L"\\\\?\\UNC\\server\\share\\<...>"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space is legal character in directory and file names.

First I propose to modify slightly your code:

```
if ((hFind = FindFirstFileA(path, &wfd)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("FindFirstFIle failed on path = \"%s\". Error %d\n", path, GetLastError());
    return 0; // I think you shouldn't abort on error, just skip this dir.
}
```

Now check error codes reported by your program.

For some paths I have got error #5 (access denied). Examples:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\CrashReports\*
c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Clean Store\*
c:\Windows\System32\config\*
```

Got two cases with code #123 (Invalid name) for path names unmanageable by `FindFirstFileA`. To correct this behavior it would be better to use wide version of function `FindFirstFileW`. See both answers for [c++ folder only search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588859/c-folder-only-search). For new Windows applications you should use wide version of API, converting with `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte` if needed.

You have also logic error. Code skips all directories and files starting with dot.

Comment: Assuming that error code `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` is raised, when a path name cannot be represented using the current ANSI code page, that can be easily addressed by using Unicode. Even if it isn't, Unicode should *always* be used with file I/O. It's safer, faster, and (potentially) relaxes many length limitations.